# Selenium webdriver: What is the substitute for browserbot?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to convert some Selenium HTML tests to use the WebDriver 2.0 framework.  According to the web site (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html), the WebDriver framework no longer supports the "browserbot" Javascript variable.  So my question is, how do I convert a command like

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getUserWindow().s.pageName</td>
    <td>Config_6_Summary_Confirm_EX</td>
</tr>
```

using WebDriver?  When I run the command

```
String target = selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().s.pageName")
```

commnand, I get an exception stating, "this.browserbot is undefined".  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1):

I make a suggestion to following.

```
String target = selenium.getEval("window.s.pageName")
```

You can access to 'browserbot' from WebDriver's getEval by "selenium.browserbot".(not "this")

```
selenium.getEval("typeof(this.browserbot)"); // undefined
selenium.getEval("typeof(selenium.browserbot)"); // object
```

but, can not use some browserbot function.
(I don't know the deference of 'enabled function' and 'disabled function'. sorry)

"getUserWindow()" is disabled.
You can use a "window" instead of it.